# Servlet cookies not working properly

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I have a login servlet where i take in email and password and direct them to a logincheck servlet. I have designed my logincheck servlet such that if the the form is submitted leaving each field filled, cookies are set to the corresponding entered values, but if the email and password fields are left blank, the cookie values are set to blank and we get directed back to the login servlet.

I am getting redirected to an error page with the description "The requested source is not available" when i submit leaving the form unfilled instead of getting redirected to the login page. Kindly help.

```
package newpackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class logincheck extends HttpServlet {

  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    //recieving form parameters
    String email=request.getParameter("email");
    String pass=request.getParameter("pass");

    //setting up cookies as a white field  if any credential has been left unfilled
    Boolean isMissingValue=false;
    if(email==null || email.trim().equals("")){
        email="";                                   //return white field as a cookie if the user doesnt enter anything and submits
        isMissingValue=true;
    }
    if(pass==null || pass.trim().equals("")){
        pass="";                                    //return white field as a cookie if the user doesnt enter anything and submits    
        isMissingValue=true;
    }

    //setting up cookies based on what the user entered last
    Cookie c1=new LongLivedCookie("email",email);
    response.addCookie(c1);
    Cookie c2=new LongLivedCookie("pass",pass);
    response.addCookie(c2);
    if(isMissingValue){
        RequestDispatcher obj=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.java");
        obj.forward(request,response);
    }
}
}
```

here is my LongLivedCookie class

```
package newpackage;

import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;

public class LongLivedCookie extends Cookie {

public static final int seconds_per_year=60*60*25*365;

public LongLivedCookie(String name, String value) {
    super(name,value);
    setMaxAge(seconds_per_year);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not instantiating your `RequestDispather` correctly.

```
RequestDispatcher obj=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.java");
```

The java docs for `RequestDispatcher` state that it

> Defines an object that receives requests from the client and sends them to any resource (such as a **servlet, HTML file, or JSP file**) on the server.

So, passing `login.java` as the target resource isn't correct. It expects you to provide the correct path to an existing servlet or JSP resource. For example, if your `Login` page is a JSP forward as

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
view.forward(request, response);
```

For a servlet the `RequestDispatcher` would need the correct URL pattern. So, if your `Login` page is a servlet check its `<url-pattern>` as specified in the `web.xml` and forward as

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Login");
```

Also note that the a `RequestDispatcher` can be retrieved from both `ServletRequest` and `ServletContext` with the difference that the former can take a ***relative path*** as well.

***Reference** :*
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html

Answer (score 0):

As per your code and description, I am assuming you are expecting the cookie values as request parameter. But cookies doesn't work in that way. To get cookie values, you will have to use HttpRequest.getCookies() method and read the values.

```
Cookies[] cookies = request.getCookies();
for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
    if (cookie.getName().equals("email")) {
         ;//logic here
    } else if (cookie.getName().equals("pass")) {
         ;//logic here.
    }
}
```

Comment: this piece of my code only sends the cookie to the client. What you are suggesting is the part where you read the cookies. I assure you i have another class with a similar kind of code as you suggest where i read cookies from the client